# How to make hash/array of params out of several selects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I have two select dropdowns and when a user selects an option from each of them It has to group them in the following manner:

```
job =>
  {
    "types" => [1,2,3]
  }
```

or at least like this:

```
job => {
  "types" => { "first" => "1", "second" => "2" }
}
```

Is this possible to do in Rails?

For example, this example only sends the last select value:

```
<%= simple_form_for @job, url: jobs_path do |f| %>

  <% 2.times do %>
    <%= f.input :types, as: :select, collection: @types %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using multiple `select` instead?

```
<%=f.select(:types, @types, multiple: true) %>
```